# Android Sign in with apple and firebase flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I'm using sign_in_with_apple and I've got the signin working for ios but the android component is not working.

I've had a look through the docs and issues where this is asked but there are no clear answers. https://github.com/aboutyou/dart_packages/tree/master/packages/sign_in_with_apple

I'm stuck on the part of the docs for this plugin that say:

> On the Sign in with Apple callback on your sever (specified in
> WebAuthenticationOptions.redirectUri), redirect safely back to your
> Android app using the following URL:
>
> intent://callback?${PARAMETERS_FROM_CALLBACK_
> BODY}#Intent;package=YOUR.PACKAGE.IDENTIFIER;scheme=signinwithapple;end
>
> **The PARAMETERS FROM CALLBACK BODY should be filled with the urlencoded
> body you receive on the endpoint from Apple's server,** and the package
> parameter should be changed to match your app's package identifier (as
> published on the Google Play Store). Leave the callback path and
> signinwithapple scheme untouched.
>
> Furthermore, when handling the incoming credentials on the client,
> make sure to only overwrite the current (guest) session of the user
> once your own server have validated the incoming code parameter, such
> that your app is not susceptible to malicious incoming links (e.g.
> logging out the current user).

The part that says: The PARAMETERS FROM CALLBACK BODY should be filled with the urlencoded body you receive on the endpoint from Apple's server. I'm unsure about how to get this and correctly format the PARAMATERS_FROM_CALLBACK_BODY part of the redirectURL to get this working for Android.

Comment: hi, do you have any update on this? I'm stuck there too. Thanks.

Comment: I am also confused what to do in this step. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was having exactly the same question and I actually opened up an [issue](https://github.com/aboutyou/dart_packages/issues/135) on their repo yesterday.

I'm not sure if you are trying to set up your own backend server for callback or not, but to answer your question, the part you were having issue to understand is only apply for someone who need to implement their own API for call back.

I did get the Apple Sign In for Android to work(via web browser auth) with the following steps:

**Note**: *Since you already got iOS part working, so I assume you got the basic configure taken care of already*.

1. Set up the glitch.com service based off their [document](https://github.com/aboutyou/dart_packages/tree/master/packages/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple#server), this part is easy to follow.
2. And then you want to implement your signInWithApple call as the following [reference](https://github.com/aboutyou/dart_packages/issues/91#issuecomment-642380267) Note: `SERVER_AS_PER_THE_DOCS` need update according to your glich service.

   ```
   Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithApple() async {
   var redirectURL = "https://SERVER_AS_PER_THE_DOCS.glitch.me/callbacks/sign_in_with_apple";
   var clientID = "AS_PER_THE_DOCS";
   final appleIdCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
       scopes: [
         AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
         AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
       ],
       webAuthenticationOptions: WebAuthenticationOptions(
           clientId: clientID,
           redirectUri: Uri.parse(
               redirectURL)));
   final oAuthProvider = OAuthProvider(providerId: 'apple.com');
   final credential = oAuthProvider.getCredential(
     idToken: appleIdCredential.identityToken,
     accessToken: appleIdCredential.authorizationCode,
   );
   final authResult =
       await SignInUtil.firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
   return authResult.user; }
   ```

Comment: Is there no way to get the redirect url to work without using whatever "Glitch" is?

Comment: @JonasZebari Sure you can, Glitch just a free host service you can leverage, But you do have some sort of service to handle the redirect tho.

Comment: Why firebase is not handling this for us? Didn't it ask for all necessary credentials (in console) before applying authentication? This sucks really :(

Comment: @CharlesC I tried using your sample code but when I run it on my device It opens my app on playstore and when I click open it says "Unhandled Exception: SignInWithAppleAuthorizationError(AuthorizationErrorCode.canceled, The user closed the Custom Tab)"

Answer (score 10):

Update 2024:

If you are using [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/changelog) version 4.4.0 and above. You don't need the `sign_in_with_apple` package to run the Apple sign in flow on any platform (Android, iOS, Windows etc...).

Just use the `signInWithProvider` method and give it an [AppleAuthProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/AppleAuthProvider-class.html) object, which is bundled in the [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/changelog) package.

```dart
AppleAuthProvider appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
appleProvider = appleProvider.addScope('email');
appleProvider = appleProvider.addScope('name');
// the line below will start the Apple sign in flow for your platform
final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
```

You will still need do the same setup as before on the Apple Developer console.

Comment: This is awesome and saved us a ton of headache. Thank you.

Comment: But in firebase console , we will not see the email address. it will be blank.

Comment: The line `appleProvider.addScope('email')` is required

Comment: Thanks so much. I was struggling to make the `sign_in_with_apple` package work on Android. Replaced everything to these 3 lines and it worked.

Comment: does this work with web?

Comment: @TenDigitGrid use signInWithPopup for web